# Spring Boot: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Tags: spring-boot, exception, transactions, spring-data-jpa, try-catch

I am trying to save exception message in DB table in Catch block but the Exception Transaction is also getting rolled back when the code passes the whole @Transactional method.

Ex:

```
@javax.transaction.Transactional
public void operationMethod(){
 serviceMethod();
}

public void serviceMethod()
 try{
 }
 catch(Exception e){
saveException(e.getMessage());
}
}

//here tried @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = Exception.class) and different combinations with Nested and Required
saveException(String exceptionMessage){
//save it into table logic
}
```

Still it is giving the "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" exception. Is there any way to force commit only saveException part without save try block and rolling back exception save.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Putting `@Transactional` on an method that is being called internally won't work (that question has been answered numerous times before on stackoverflow).

Comment: @M.Deinum even if doing save exception operation in catch block itself giving the same exception. Is there any work around.

Comment: Again starting a new transaction has been answered many times before. In short put that save method n a different external service.

Comment: not working even it is moved different service class

Comment: You will need to mark it with the annotation and make sure it starts a new transaction. Else it won't work.

Comment: There Might be error in your transaction, log the error in catch blog and see what causes failure while saving error message